# Multithreaded downloading a single file in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

I have an array with an object 'Chunk' which looks like this:

```
typedef enum
{
Connecting = 0,
Downloading,
Finished,
Error
} State;

@interface Chunk : NSObject

@property (atomic) uint64_t startingByte;
@property (atomic) uint64_t endingByte;
@property (atomic) NSString *md5;
@property (atomic) State *chunkState;

@end
```

There's also a Download object which holds the link to the file, its size and downloadedBytes. The download objects has an array as a property (which holds chunks).

What's the best way to download the file in for example 6 threads? Each thread downloading one chunk at a time (the idea it to merge them at the end). Should I use gdc or somekind of a queue system?

Comment: did you figure out this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Given that the network is generally the bottleneck, downloading multiple chunks simultaneously from a single server isn't going to be any faster.  In fact, it'll likely be slower because of contention.   Safari, et. al., will start multiple downloads to *different* servers because a lot of a web page content can be rendered well before the download completes and there is negotiation costs with each different server, none of which is likely applicable in this case.

If you really do need to do this, the best bet would be to use multiple asynchronous URL connections using the built in classes and let the system handle the concurrency itself.

Comment: My app will be downloading files from CDN, there is a significant difference in terms of speed when downloading with multiple threads.

Comment: Ahh -- OK -- that'd be the rare case.  If you are bandwidth throttled on the remote side or in between, then -- sure -- go for multiple channels.   Use multiple asynchronous NSURLConnections (they'll deal with queueing behind the scenes).